# using Ajax.BeginForm ViewModel post is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having an issue with my ajax form :
i have this code

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "SyntheseEvt",
                                            FormMethod.Post,
                                            new AjaxOptions
                                            {
                                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                HttpMethod = "POST",
                                                UpdateTargetId = "search-results"
                                            }
                                            ))

        {
        <div class="row">
        @{
         CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;


        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="dx-field-label">@Resources.Resource.DDebut</div>
            <div class="dx-field-value">
                @(Html.DevExtreme().DateBox()
                        .ID("DtDebut")
                        .Type(DateBoxType.Date)
                        .Value(Model.paramSynthese.DtDebut_c)
                    .DisplayFormat(currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)
                )
```

With that model

```
public class SearchSyntheseEvtViewModel
{
    public C_DAL_TRS_ATELIER DAL_TRS_ATELIER_c;
    public List<C_BEL_TRS_ATELIER> ListBEL_TRS_ATELIER_c;
    public C_DAL_TRS_MACHINE DAL_TRS_MACHINE_c;
    public List<C_BEL_TRS_MACHINE> ListBEL_TRS_MACHINE;
    public ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel paramSynthese;


    public  SearchSyntheseEvtViewModel()
    {
    }
    public SearchSyntheseEvtViewModel Initialiser()
    {
        this.DAL_TRS_ATELIER_c = new C_DAL_TRS_ATELIER(C_Interface_Meta.Mesbdd_p, C_Interface_Meta.IndexBdd_p);
        this.DAL_TRS_MACHINE_c = new C_DAL_TRS_MACHINE(C_Interface_Meta.Mesbdd_p, C_Interface_Meta.IndexBdd_p);
        paramSynthese = new ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel();
        paramSynthese = paramSynthese.Initialiser();
        paramSynthese = paramSynthese.Charger();
        return this;
    }
    public SearchSyntheseEvtViewModel Charger()
    {
        DAL_TRS_ATELIER_c.Charger(ref ListBEL_TRS_ATELIER_c);
        DAL_TRS_MACHINE_c.Charger(ref ListBEL_TRS_MACHINE);
        return this;
    }
}


public class ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel
{
    public string AT_ID_c { get; set; }
    public string TR_ID_c { get; set; }
    public DateTime DtDebut_c;
    public DateTime DtFin_c;
    public Metaproductique.Kmprod.Km_Synthese_Moteur.C_SyntheseEvenement Moteur_c { get; set; }
    public List<string> MA_ID_c { get; set; }
    public List<string> RE_ID_c { get; set; }
    public C_SyntheseEvenement.Regroupement Regroupement_c { get; set; }
    public C_SyntheseEvenement.Type Type_c { get; set; }
    public DataSet DsDonnees_c = new DataSet();
    public string Requete;
    public ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel()
    {
    }
    public ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel Initialiser()
    {
        Moteur_c = new Metaproductique.Kmprod.Km_Synthese_Moteur.C_SyntheseEvenement();
        Moteur_c.Initialiser(C_Interface_Meta.Mesbdd_p, C_Interface_Meta.IndexBdd_p);
        DtDebut_c = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        DtFin_c = DateTime.Now;
        return this;
    }


    public ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel Charger()
    {
        return this;
    }
public class SearchSyntheseEvtViewModel
{
    public C_DAL_TRS_ATELIER DAL_TRS_ATELIER_c;
    public List<C_BEL_TRS_ATELIER> ListBEL_TRS_ATELIER_c;
    public C_DAL_TRS_MACHINE DAL_TRS_MACHINE_c;
    public List<C_BEL_TRS_MACHINE> ListBEL_TRS_MACHINE;
    public ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel paramSynthese;


    public  SearchSyntheseEvtViewModel()
    {
    }
    public SearchSyntheseEvtViewModel Initialiser()
    {
        this.DAL_TRS_ATELIER_c = new C_DAL_TRS_ATELIER(C_Interface_Meta.Mesbdd_p, C_Interface_Meta.IndexBdd_p);
        this.DAL_TRS_MACHINE_c = new C_DAL_TRS_MACHINE(C_Interface_Meta.Mesbdd_p, C_Interface_Meta.IndexBdd_p);
        paramSynthese = new ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel();
        paramSynthese = paramSynthese.Initialiser();
        paramSynthese = paramSynthese.Charger();
        return this;
    }
    public SearchSyntheseEvtViewModel Charger()
    {
        DAL_TRS_ATELIER_c.Charger(ref ListBEL_TRS_ATELIER_c);
        DAL_TRS_MACHINE_c.Charger(ref ListBEL_TRS_MACHINE);
        return this;
    }
}


public class ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel
{
    public string AT_ID_c { get; set; }
    public string TR_ID_c { get; set; }
    public DateTime DtDebut_c;
    public DateTime DtFin_c;
    public Metaproductique.Kmprod.Km_Synthese_Moteur.C_SyntheseEvenement Moteur_c { get; set; }
    public List<string> MA_ID_c { get; set; }
    public List<string> RE_ID_c { get; set; }
    public C_SyntheseEvenement.Regroupement Regroupement_c { get; set; }
    public C_SyntheseEvenement.Type Type_c { get; set; }
    public DataSet DsDonnees_c = new DataSet();
    public string Requete;
    public ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel()
    {
    }
    public ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel Initialiser()
    {
        Moteur_c = new Metaproductique.Kmprod.Km_Synthese_Moteur.C_SyntheseEvenement();
        Moteur_c.Initialiser(C_Interface_Meta.Mesbdd_p, C_Interface_Meta.IndexBdd_p);
        DtDebut_c = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        DtFin_c = DateTime.Now;
        return this;
    }


    public ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel Charger()
    {

        return this;
    }
```

And in controller i reach my method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(SearchSyntheseEvtViewModel search)
    {
        ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel myParams;


        myParams = search.paramSynthese;
        if (myParams != null)
        {
```

but everything in my search ViewModel is null ...

I'm thinking it's about the devextreme html element.
I'm trying to bind my nested model ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel to the post action in the controller –

Does someone have any idea ?

Comment: The `name` attributes of your form controls must match the names of the properties in your model. Its not even clear what you are trying to bind to

Comment: We do not even know what the model is in the view! And if it is `SearchSyntheseEvtViewModel`, then nothing would bind because it does not even have any properties, just fields which the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot set

Comment: the model in the view is the parent model 
@model SearchSyntheseEvtViewModel

Comment: I'm trying to bind my nested model ParamSyntheseEvtViewModel  to the post action in the controller

Comment: Read my previous comments! You cannot bind to fields, and the `name` attribute of your input would need to be `name="paramSynthese.DtDebut_c"`

Comment: but the name is from devextreme isnt it ?

Comment: Is it? (all you set is the `.Value`) - I cannot see what html you have generated

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i'solved it : i was missing the get / set property on my sub model !